# How to detect a drop that is external to a WFP App

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a WPF window which is displaying the contents of a folder (ListView) and have implemented drag and drop of files from the window to the desktop or an explorer window (using GongSolutions Drag Drop Library).

I can detect drops within the app no problem, but I need to detect when the drop happens outside the app (Desktop or Explorer Window) so I can refresh the window to reflect the file having moved.

Is there any way to detect a drop happening outside of the app?

I know I can use a FileSystemWatcher to detect the file leaving, but this has the downside that if the user drags and drops multiple files at once it fires off loads of times. Grouping the FileSystemWatcher events using a timer obviously creates a delay due to the timer, hence the reason I want to detect the drop, so I can refresh once immediately after the drop happens.

Comment: If I get it correctly, your eventual aim is to detect the changes in the contents of the folder that you display in the `ListView` and refresh the `ListView` accordingly. What if the user cuts a file in Windows Explorer and pastes it to another folder, that is *without using drag-n-drop*? I believe using the `FileSystemWatcher` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to track mouse position outside the WPF application we need
> to hook and subscribe to the messages of whole Windows OS and filter
> only we are interesting in. Great blog post about how to capture
> mouse messages regardless of the  mouse position can be found **here**.

The **here** link was broken so I didn't add it's hyperlink to the quote.

The above paragraph is quoted from [**developer.de** blog](https://developers.de/blogs/bahro/archive/2014/05/04/drag-and-drop-item-outside-wpf-application.aspx). you can find your answer about checking drop outside the WPF application window. This is also the link to the [sample project files](https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=8B11BBBF3F0ED903&resid=8B11BBBF3F0ED903%2150827&authkey=AKJr_scsSHWRgCM) on OneDrive.

> First we need a property to indicate when the mouse is outside the
> application.

```
public static bool IsMouseOutsideApp 
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

> Then we need to modify HookCallback method so that when the Left mouse
> button is up, and set the property (IsMouseOutsideApp ) to true if the
> mouse outside the application.

```
internal static IntPtr HookCallback( int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP == (MouseMessages)wParam)
    {
        MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));

        //check if POint in main window
        Point pt = new Point(hookStruct.pt.x, hookStruct.pt.y);
        var ptw = App.Current.MainWindow.PointFromScreen(pt);
        var w = App.Current.MainWindow.Width;
        var h = App.Current.MainWindow.Height;
        //if point is outside MainWindow
        if (ptw.X < 0 || ptw.Y < 0 || ptw.X > w || ptw.Y > h)
            IsMouseOutsideApp = true;
        else
            IsMouseOutsideApp = false;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(m_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

> The Last thing we need to implement is **DragSourceQueryContinueDrag**
> event. The implementation is straightforward:

```
/// <summary>
/// Continuosly tracking Dragging mouse position
/// </summary>
/// 
/// 
private void DragSourceQueryContinueDrag(object sender, QueryContinueDragEventArgs e)
{
    //when keystate is non, draop is heppen
    if (e.KeyStates == DragDropKeyStates.None)
    {
        //unsubscribe event
        this.QueryContinueDrag -= queryhandler;
        e.Handled = true;
        //Unhooking on Mouse Up
        InterceptMouse.UnhookWindowsHookEx(InterceptMouse.m_hookID);

        //notifiy user about drop result
        Task.Run(
            () =>;
            {
                //Drop hepend outside Instantly app
                if (InterceptMouse.IsMouseOutsideApp)
                    MessageBox.Show("Dragged outside app");
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("Dragged inside app");
            }
            );
    }
}
```